# dynamically load file to html tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load the tab contents dynamically from different html page. When I click EROs tab it should display the contents from /SVB/Tax_Eros.html file without reloading the page. Likewise when Import tab is clicked it should display the contents from /SVB/Tax_Imports

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active" >
        <a href="/SVB/Tax_Eros" id="eros">EROs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/SVB/Tax_Imports" id="imports">Imports</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/SVB/Tax_Accounting" id="accounting">Accounting</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content clear-fix">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="eros">
            <script>
                $('#eros').click(function(){
                    $('#Taxeros').load($(this).attr('href'));
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="imports">
            <script>
                 $('#imports').click(function(){
                    $('#Taximports').load($(this).attr('href'));
                 });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="accounting">
            <script>
                $('#accounting').click(function(){
                    $('#Taxaccounting').load($(this).attr('href'));
                });
            </script>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"When I click"*  So you need a click event handler.  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
 You haven't bound event handlers to your anchors. The second half of your code in the `.tab-content` element makes no sense what so ever.

Comment: @Taplar I added click function now..

Comment: @hungerstar i did edit the code. The tab is working fine, when I click the tab it navigates to the corresponding html pages. But it's not displaying the content below the tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap Tabs (3.3.7) you will need to modify your markup as Bootstrap expects certain conventions for it to do its magic without configuring a bunch of JS.

Instead of placing the page you need to load in the `href` attribute we place it in a custom `data-src` attribute. Bootstrap expects the value of the `href` attribute to be the ID of the tab pane associated with the tab. We also added `data-toggle="tab"` as that is required for Bootstrap Tabs to function.

It looked like you were trying to load content on tab click but that isn't useful for the default tab and it's tab pane as there won't be any content in it initially. So we've passed a function to jQuery that will get executed when the DOM is ready. This function will parse the tabs and load content into the tab panes based on the attribute values.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.nav-tabs a').each(function(index, el) {

    var $this = $(this);
    var pane = $this.attr('href');
    var src = $this.data('src');

    $(pane).load(src);

  });

});
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a data-src="/SVB/Tax_Eros" href="#eros" data-toggle="tab">EROs</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-src="/SVB/Tax_Imports" href="#imports" data-toggle="tab">Imports</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-src="/SVB/Tax_Accounting" href="#accounting" data-toggle="tab">Accounting</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content clear-fix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="eros">1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="imports">2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="accounting">3</div>
</div>
```

As far as I know, Stack Snippets cannot mock Ajax requests so here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43fej1fz/4/) and a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xGL9qYd1xsO9dqCFFqOe?p=preview) that do.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Did you change the `id` on the links to `data-tab-id`?

Comment: When i click EROs tab it should display the content from /SVB/Tax_Eros html file. Likewise when I click Imports tab it should display contents from /SVB/Tax_Imports

Comment: I get that. What you're not being clear on is **exactly** where it should go. I'm assuming it's the `/SVB/Tax_Eros` link is going to have it's content displayed in `<div class="tab-pane active" id="eros"></div>`.

Comment: I created [this demo code](https://pastebin.com/raw/aSvifcii) and it seems to be working fine. Instead of HTML files, I have simple text files that load in some words but should work the same. This code loads the content from `/content/one.txt` into the `<div class="tab-pane active" id="eros"></div>` pane.

Comment: thanks for the input.. I tried the code but whenever I click the tabs it is not displaying anything.. but when i click EROS after I clicked other tabs it is displaying EROS content then when I click other tabs it is still showing the same ERO content..

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with your tabs. This is why you need to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a partial like you've provided. It becomes too much work to go back and forth when we don't have all the moving parts.

Comment: The code I've provided is modeled off of your code which will load content into a tab pane once a tab has been clicked, not before.

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap and some of the markup for tabbed content might not be set up properly on your end. Here is a variation of the code above that works with Bootstrap. It also loads tab pane content on page load instead of having to click a tab first. In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43fej1fz/4/) there's some code you won't need, it's there to fake the ajax request that the jQuery `.load()` method does.

Comment: That doesn't include the JavaScript for Bootstrap which is required for the tabs to work. You'll also need to change the markup a bit for your tabs. Please see the JSFiddle I added to the bottom of my answer. The markup there aligns with the requirements of Bootstrap tabs.

Comment: Yes.. The fiddle is working perfectly.. If you could post it separately I will mark it as a right answer.. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

  $('.nav-tabs a').each(function(index, el) {

    var $this = $(this);
    var pane = $this.attr('href');
    var src = $this.data('src');

    $(pane).load(src);

  });

});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a data-src="/SVB/Tax_Eros" href="#eros" data-toggle="tab">EROs</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-src="/SVB/Tax_Imports" href="#imports" data-toggle="tab">Imports</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-src="/SVB/Tax_Accounting" href="#accounting" data-toggle="tab">Accounting</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content clear-fix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="eros">1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="imports">2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="accounting">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function clicks () {
       var myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.eros') || null;
       if (myButtons != null){
       for (var i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++){
          myButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
             var url = this.getAttribute('data-href'); // location to load
             var obj = this.getAttribute('data-id');//id to append content
             var type = 'GET';  /*-> post or get-> if is 'post' page must be in Php or other server language*/ 
             data = '';
             var objElm = document.querySelector('#'+obj) || null;
             if (objElm === null){console.log('no element to write content'); return;}
             xmlRequest (url, type, data, obj)
          }, !1);
       }
   }
}
function xmlRequest (url, type, data, obj){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest || null;
    if (chr === null){console.log('Obsolete browser');return;}
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
       if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
          obj.innerHTML = this.responseText;
       }
       else {console.log('Error')}
    }, !1);
    xhr.open(type, url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'Application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data)
}
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      clicks ();
   }, !1)
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active" >
            <a data-href="/SVB/Tax_Eros" data-toggle="tab" data-id="eros" class="eros">EROs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-href="/SVB/Tax_Imports" data-toggle="tab" data-id="imports" class="eros">Imports</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-href="/SVB/Tax_Accounting" data-toggle="tab" data-id="accounting" class="eros">Accounting</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content clear-fix">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="eros"> </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="imports"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="accounting"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry, it have a bug... in this step you must use "objElm " mot "obj"
if (objElm === null){console.log('no element to write content'); return;}
             xmlRequest (url, type, data, objElm )

Comment: Great solution. But it is only displaying the Tax_Eros page but not the other pages..

Comment: sorry, chr is xhr,

Comment: "But it is only displaying the Tax_Eros page but not the other pages.."

Link are real?